# Unrecognized request: { _request: evaluate } in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

This is my java code on visual studio code when I try to run it on visual studio code and enter a number it says: Unrecognized request: { _request: evaluate } ...
What should I do to disappear this message when I use visual studio code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input number : ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(number);

        int result = (number >= 0) ? number : -number ;
        System.out.println(result);

        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [VSCode Java Debugging Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_debug-session-inputs) you have to use a terminal as console like the integrated Terminal instead of the internal console.

> The default Debug Console in VS Code doesn't support inputs. If your program need inputs from a terminal , you can use the Integrated Terminal (Ctrl+`) within VS Code or an external terminal to launch it.

You also can set the *console* property in your *launch.json* to *integratedTerminal* or *externalTerminal*, so you will use it every debug session.

Answer (score 0):

enter in "configurations" in Java Debugger.

change in the field java > debug > Settings:Console, and select IntegratedTerminal.